# Why to evaluate a N period function we need to go up to N^2 and not just up to 2N

Tags: shors-algorithm, fourier-sampling, period-finding-algorithm, factorization

I know about the answer of a similar question here:
[Reason for evaluating $a^x \bmod N$ from $x = 0$ to $N^2$](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/reason-for-evaluating-ax-bmod-n-from-x-0-to-n2).

But the answer there seems to explain the reason in terms of real qubits (chance of them collapsing to some state or not) plus the undersampling criteria (Nyquist Theorem). My question here is about purely logical qubits.

$f_{a,N}(x) = a^x \bmod N$. The period that we want to find is $r$ such that $f_{a,N}(x+r) = f_{a,N}(x)$. Since for all $a$ and $N$, $f(0)=1$ and we are assuming that the function is periodic, we need to find another $f(x)=1$. This $x$ will be our estimate for $r$.

Having found $r, r \neq 0$ such that $f(r)=1$, if we want to confirm our result we could go to $f(2r)$ and get again $f(2r)=1$.

The biggest value that $f(x)$ can have is $N$. The function is discrete. Therefore in at least $N$ trials we would find an $x=r, r \neq 0$ such that $f(x)=1$. To satisfy Nyquist criteria we would need to go at most to $2N$ trials. In $2N$ trials of $x$ we will find two instances of $f(x)=1$ and our period would be found and confirmed.

Therefore why in theory it is said that we need $N^2$ trials and not $2N$ trials?

Comment: I haven’t worked it out, but I think if you evaluate only up to $2N$ you’d need to sample many more times to get an estimate for $r$. Have you tried this for small enough $N$? Just choose a vector of -60 bits that’s almost all $0$ except for two that are $1$, spaced apart reasonably by around $r=~30$ indices, and calculate the Fourier transform?

Comment: Hummmmm, good point. I got curious about it because in Yanofsky's book Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists he says this without proof when starting explaining Shor's. If you do the math (without yet having considered the QFT and the sampling question that comes with it) you will get to 2N and not $N^2$. And then I started asking myself, but why???.

Comment: There might be a time-space trade off. You might evaluate up to 2N, but need to repeat N times. Or you could double your number of qubits, evaluate up to $N^2$, but only one time needed. Let me know what you find out!

Comment: By the way, soon after I have posted my question I found this pdf on the internet: https://young.physics.ucsc.edu/150/shor.pdf . The author at the explanation beggining says something on your line of reasoning. I will look at it in more detail. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It's because the difference between fractions with denominators $\leq N$ can be as small as $1/N^2$, and the closest fractions always have different denominators, and your goal is to learn the denominator.

Comment: You mean $lim_{\delta_1 \rightarrow 0, \delta_2 \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{N-\delta_1} - \frac{1}{N-\delta_2} = \frac{1}{N^2-(\delta_1 + \delta_2)N+\delta_1.\delta_2} = \frac{1}{N^2}$. Now I need to move forward in Yanofsky book and understand the final steps of Shor's. In other words, I need to deepen my understanding of QFT. Thanks!